# eks anywhere cluster creation stuck

Tags: amazon-eks, eksctl

I am trying to create eks anywhere local cluster on centos machine. However, the cluster creation is stuck and I don't see any more output on the screen. I have enabled debug to more output. Please see screenshot of the logs advise if I am missing anything. I have been following below link to create eks anywhere local cluster.

Link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-eks-anywhere-now-generally-available-to-create-and-manage-kubernetes-clusters-on-premises/

Here is the screenshot of the logs:

[logs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n40oT.png)

Here is the screenshot of the cluster create yaml file

[cluster create yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rSDR.png)

Comment: Can you tell what's your operating system (uname -r), docker version (docker info | grep "Server Version") and memory usage status (free -h)

Comment: Please find below: 


`[root@test-1 ~]# uname -r`
3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64

`[root@test-1 ~]# free -h`
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        2.5G        7.6G         19M        5.4G         12G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
[root@test-1 ~]# docker info | grep "Server Version"
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
WARNING: the overlay storage-driver is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release.
 Server Version: 20.10.6`

Comment: Mem free: 7.6G
Docker Server Version: 20.10.6
OS: Centos7 (3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64)

Comment: Looking at the screen shot, the command that your red arrow pointed was to apply a spec located at the directory **./dev-cluster/generated/dev-cluster-ekas-a-cluster.yaml**. Upon applied the spec the process then wait on the readiness of the deployment in namespace **eksa-system**. To find out why the wait has gone timeout: **kubectl --kubeconfig dev-cluster/generated/dev-cluster.kind.kubeconfig get pods -n eksa-system -o wide**. From here you can further troubleshoot with common kubectl commands such as describe, logs. Good understanding of [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) is essential here.

Comment: @gohm'c  I don't see any pods or containers in that name space.